# Using "read" to set variables

Tags: linux, macos, bash, variables

In `bash` from the CLI I can do:

```
$ ERR_TYPE=$"OVERLOAD"
$ echo $ERR_TYPE
OVERLOAD
$ read ${ERR_TYPE}_ERROR
1234
$ echo $OVERLOAD_ERROR
1234
```

This works great to set my variable name dynamically; in a script it doesn't work. I tried:

```
#!/bin/env bash

ERR_TYPE=("${ERR_TYPE[@]}" "OVERLOAD" "PANIC" "FATAL")

for i in "${ERR_TYPE[@]}"
do
   sh -c $(echo ${i}_ERROR=$"1234")
done
echo $OVERLOAD_ERROR # output is blank

   # I also tried these:
   # ${i}_ERROR=$(echo ${i}_ERROR=$"1234") # command not found
   # read ${i}_ERROR=$(echo ${i}_ERROR=$"1234") # it never terminates
```

How would I set a variable as I do from CLI, but in a script? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use dynamic variables names instead of associative arrays, you really need to question your approach.

```
err_type=("OVERLOAD" "PANIC" "FATAL")
declare -A error
for type in "${err_type[@]}"; do
    error[$type]=1234
done
```

Nevertheless, in bash you'd use `declare`:

```
declare "${i}_error=1234"
```

Your approach fails because you spawn a new shell, passing the command `OVERLOAD_ERROR=1234`, and then the shell exits. Your current shell is not affected at all.

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPSVARNAMES. One day you'll write `PATH=...` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: About the `declare` function vs `eval`, is the latter not really even intended to use it for setting variables? S. Klumpers method works, but I didn't accept an answer yet because I wanted to make sure. THANKS!, oops I mean thanks! (ALLCAPS=not good practice noted)...

Comment: `eval` is intended to evaluate a string as shell code, not specifically about variables. `declare` is intended to create variables, perhaps with a certain attribute (such as associative/indexed array, integer, lower case, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `eval`.
I think this would be considered bad practice though (it had some thing to do with the fact that `eval` is "evil" because it allows bad input or something):

```
eval "${i}_ERROR=1234"
```

Comment: I fixed it, when in doubt just add more evals.

Comment: Hey look at you! you will forever be known as "Dr. Eva!"! :D ... yes that works... but like you said is it the right way? I'm a bit nervous even though it is working, or even how it's working and why. If it's possible to use "read" in a while loop I wouldn't mind either... it's just that I'm not familiar enough with while loops and read that I can make it terminate for whatever reason. If it can't be done and this is the only way I'll gladly accept your answer... thanks again

Comment: The eval command works by evaluating all expressions and returning the result, the echo prints it and because it's in a subshell that will be the argument of the next eval.

Comment: And you can read in a loop, although for your dynamic variable to work it would need this trick again.

Comment: `eval` is not evil at all… only _bad usages of `eval`_ are evil. And sorry to tell, but this answer is terrible. At least, use `eval "${i}_ERROR=1234"`.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable will hold a number, you can use `let`.

```
#!/bin/bash

ERR_TYPE=("OVERLOAD" "PANIC" "FATAL")

j=0
for i in "${ERR_TYPE[@]}"
do
  let ${i}_ERROR=1000+j++
done
echo $OVERLOAD_ERROR
echo $PANIC_ERROR
echo $FATAL_ERROR
```

This outputs:

```
1000
1001
1002
```

Comment: The part I'm appending can be a number or string. Thanks for the answer though, I didn't know about `let` before - and good to know it's meant for numbers.